# Where is my Native Ads Advanced (Unified) ID?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I assessed to Admob => Add Unit.
Just only three options showed me: `Banner, interstitial, and rewarded`

But in https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-unified 
they show me two more ad formats are `Native Ads Advanced (Unified)` and `Native Ads Advanced`

They also showed the ID in there content but I don't know that it's mine or not

I am so sorry if it's kind of a stupid question but I have no idea and I need your help. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on top of [the page linked](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-unified), it says:

> Native Ads Advanced is currently released to a limited set of
>   publishers. If you're interested in participating, reach out to your
>   account manager to discuss the possibility.

Native Ads are only available as Ad Units, if the feature is unlocked for you by an account manager. I am facing the same problem and Google seems to be very strict, when deciding who to add to the "limited set of publishers".
A sample for a google group, where this has been demanded:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/f0Ngf-qvYmk